# Why would code work in code snippet but not when I try to run it myself?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I'm creating a program that validates some user info and uses a drop down list to get user choice, then the quantity of items the user wants and outputs the value. When I previously asked a question here it works fine on code snippet, but when I run it, it will not give me the total cost.. Does anyone know what could be causing it?

**My code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="externalJS.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>PLease complete the below form to book one of our dives: </p>


<form name = "myForm" onsubmit = "return validate()" method="post">
<table>

  <tr>
      <td><label for="name">Name:</label><br></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name"  /><br></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

      <td><label for="email">Email address: </label><br></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="email" /></td><br>

      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td> <label for="phoneNumber">Phone number: </label><br></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" /></td><br>
      </tr>


         <tr>
          <td><label for="diveChoice">Please select which dive you would like to purchase: </label></td>
          <td><select id="diveChoice">
            <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected"> Select option</option>
            <option value="cenote">Cenote Dive</option>
            <option value="shark">Dive with Bull Sharks</option>
            <option value="reef">Reef Dive</option></td>
          </select></td>
         </tr>

            <!-- number input to get amount of dives required -->
            <tr>
            <td> <label for="quantity"> How many people are coming to on the dive? </label></td>
            <td> <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min=1></td><br>
            </tr>

         <tr>
           <td><label> Total cost: </label></td>
           <td><input type="text" id="total" /><br></td>
         </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><input type= "submit" value ="Submit" /> </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

**My javascript code:**

```
function validate(){
var x = document.getElementById("name").value;
var y = document.getElementById("email").value;
var z = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;

if (x == ""){
alert("Please provide a name");
return false
}


if (y == ""){
    alert("Please provide an email address");
    return false
}

if (z == ""){
        alert("Please provide a phone number");
        return false
    }

  }


 function totalCost(){
 var dive = document.getElementById("diveChoice").value;
 var amount = document.getElementById("quantity").value;

 if (dive === "cenote"){
     document.getElementById("total").value =
     amount * 150;
     }

if (dive === "shark"){
     document.getElementById("total").value =
     amount * 200;
     }

if (dive === "reef"){
     document.getElementById("total").value =
     amount * 100;
 }
}

document.getElementById('diveChoice').addEventListener('change', totalCost);
document.getElementById('quantity').addEventListener('change', totalCost);
```

Am I missing something from the opening of my html file? I know the external js file is linked correctly as user input validation works. Many thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Yeah I get a JAVA error, but I haven't wrote anything in JAVA? This is the error: Error: Could not find or load main class book
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: book

Comment: My html page is saved with the name book.html

Comment: How do we know? We cannot see the `externalJS.js` nor do we know how you serve the HTML.

Comment: You can add to the script tag the `type=text/javascript` attribute.

Comment: I have updated the question with my code now

Comment: @user17517503 thanks for that, I've updated it, but still the same issue

Comment: Do you get the same error at the all browser? if not, which browser(s)?

Comment: @user17517503 on my laptop I've only got microsoft edge, and google chrome. Tried it on both, and both give the same result

Comment: Do the other pages/scripts working successfully?

Comment: Yeah everything else is fine, even where I validate where the person enters their details is ok. It's just the section to work out the total is not working

Comment: it must be an issue with the total box, because no number goes in at all but I cannot figure out the issue